# basic question about the meaning of "functions defined on a variety"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am a beginner in alegbraic geometry. I am trying to understand what the statement "function on a variety" means. Consider this extract taken [from here](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/vbraun/toric-varieties-lecture/downloads/ToricVarietiesLectureNotes.pdf):

[image]

Working in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ take for example $X = V( \langle x^2 \rangle) $ and the polynomial $x^2+1$ . What does it mean for that polynomial to "define a function on $X$" ?

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ then $V(I) = \{ x_1,\ldots,x_n\in \mathbb{C}^n, \forall f\in I, f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = 0\}$ is just a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and for any polynomial $h \in \mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in V(I)$ you can evaluate $h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. The main point is that for $I$ equal to its radical ideal then the ring of polynomial functions on $V(I)$ is exactly the same as $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in this setup, the points in $X$ are points living in $\mathbb{C}$. In other words, if I say $V(\langle x^2\rangle)$, then I mean the set of elements $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $c^2 = 0$. What I've just done is taken a polynomial $f(x) = x^2$, plugged in the value $c$, and tested whether I got zero. In this case, $f(x)$ defines a function on $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, the functions on $\mathbb{C}$ morally should just be polynomials, at least when we restrict our attention to *algebraic* geometry (if you do, say, differential geometry then you might care about holomorphic things, which are no longer polynomials in general).

So what about if you say "functions on $X = V(\langle x^2 \rangle)$"? Well, elements of $X$ still are still elements of $\mathbb{C}$, but it just so happens that the only element $c$ such that $c^2 = 0$ is $c = 0$. So $X = \{0\}$. Now, any polynomial, say $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ as in your example, is still a function on $X$, in the sense that I can pick any point of $X$ (which is some complex number) and plug it into $f$. But it just so happens that the only point of $X$ is $0$, and $f(0) = 1$. So even though $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ and the other constant polynomial $g(x) = 1$ are different polynomials, they still define the same function on $X$, because $f(0) = 1 = g(0)$. Formally, this means that really the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of functions on $X$ (which also uniquely determines $X$ under some appropriate equivalence of categories) is just $\mathbb{C}[x]/\sqrt{(x^2)} = \mathbb{C}[x]/(x) = \mathbb{C}$: in other words, the only part of the polynomial that matters is the constant term, which is expressed by the fact that we took the quotient by the ideal generated by $x$.

So in this setting, a function should really just be a map $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ which is the restriction of a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ (which gives a map $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by plugging in complex numbers) to $X$. More generally, there's a notion of a "regular function" on a variety or scheme, which basically means "looks like a polynomial affine-locally" but where you're no longer working in affine space.

Of course from this perspective (this "classical" perspective of varieties), you do lose a bit of information: the $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]/(x))$ is only the reduced subscheme of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2))$, which means you've lost track of multiplicity at $0$.

Comment: many thanks for a very clear answer !